# What are the eigenvalues of this $6 \times 6$ matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> What are the eigenvalues of the following matrix?
>
> $$A=\left(\begin{matrix} 
>   0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0&0\\
>   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1&0\\
>   0 & 0& 0 & 0 & 0&1\\
>   1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0&0\\
>   0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0&0\\0&0&1&0&0&0
> \end{matrix}\right)$$

My attempt: I know how  to find the eigenvalues of a $2 \times 2$ matrix and of a $3 \times 3$ matrix. But here I am very confused, as I don't know how to find the eigenvalues of a $6 \times 6$ matrix.

Is there any easy method or some tricky method?

Comment: *as i know how to find the eigenvalue of 2×2 matrix and 3×3 matrix ,as here i m very confused as i don't know how to find the eigenvalue in 6×6 matrix.* $$$$ This is your attempt??

Comment: soory @TheSimpliFire..im very confused

Comment: @stupid And what's your method in the case of $3\times3$ matrices?

Comment: If you want a somewhat tricky answer... Considering this matrix as a linear transform, what does this linear transform do? If you are clear about this, you should be able to figure out a complete set of eigenvectors.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos      suppose $A= \begin{pmatrix}
1 &1  &0 \\ 
1 & 0 &0 \\ 
0 & 0 &0 
\end{pmatrix}$ to find the eigenvalue  we  used $A - \lambda I= 0$

Comment: @HwChu..im not getting  can u elaborate  with matrix?

Comment: @stupid That doesn't make sense. Perhaps that you meant $\det(A-\lambda\operatorname{Id})=0$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos,,..yaa..u r right

Comment: This is a *circulant matrix*.

Comment: okks...now  i know @LordSharktheUnknown

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case, the simplest way to analyze it is to simply see what it does to vectors.

$A \left(\begin{matrix} 
 a\\
 b\\
 c\\
 d\\
e\\f
\end{matrix}\right) =  \left(\begin{matrix} 
 d\\
 e\\
 f\\
 a\\
b\\c
\end{matrix}\right)$

So for an eigenvector, we have

$A \left(\begin{matrix} 
 a\\
 b\\
 c\\
 d\\
e\\f
\end{matrix}\right) =  \left(\begin{matrix} 
 d\\
 e\\
 f\\
 a\\
b\\c
\end{matrix}\right) =\lambda \left(\begin{matrix} 
 a\\
 b\\
 c\\
 d\\
e\\f
\end{matrix}\right)$

So $d=\lambda a $ and $a = \lambda d$, hence $a = \lambda^2 a$, so $\lambda = \pm 1$.

You can also observe that if you apply $A$ to a vector, and apply $A$ to the result, you get the original vector. So $A^2=I$, and the minimal polynomial of A is $t^2-1$, which has roots $\pm1$.

Comment: amazing answer@ accumulation

Answer (score 6):

Hint:

You  can use the fact that for a block matrix we have ( see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement)):

$$
\det \begin{pmatrix}
A&B\\
C&D
\end{pmatrix}= \det (A-BD^{-1}C)\det D
$$

In this case $B$ and $C$ are the identity matrices and $A,D$ are diagonal, so the result is simple

Comment: $
\det \begin{pmatrix}
A&B\\
C&D
\end{pmatrix}= \det (A-BD^{-1}C)\det D
= \det(0 - I.0.I) 0 =0 $  here  how  can i find the eigenvalue,,im not getting

Comment: The diagonal elements of $A-\lambda I$ are $0-\lambda=-\lambda$, not $0$.

Comment: yaaa  ..@Emilio  novati    i got it  now   that  mean  eigenvalue will be +1,-1

Comment: But D is singular.

Comment: @Acccumulation For $\lambda=0$, yes, but not otherwise. Thus you need to separately check whether $0$ is an eigenvalue, but otherwise this formula works.

Answer (score 4):

A permutation of the rows and columns (a change of basis which preserves eigenvalues) transforms your matrix into
$$
A=\left(\begin{matrix} 
  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0&0\\
  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0&0\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0&0\\
  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0&0\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0&1
\\0&0&0&0&1&0
\end{matrix}\right)
$$
which is the direct sum of three copies of $B=\left(\begin{matrix} 
  0 & 1\\
1 & 0
\end{matrix}\right)$. Hence its eigenvalues are those of $B$, i.e., $1$ and $-1$, both with multiplicity 3 (algebraic and geometric).

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**

Let observe that

$$A(e_1+e_4)=1\cdot (e_1+e_4)$$

$$A(e_1-e_4)=-1\cdot (e_1-e_4)$$

and similarly for others combinations.

Comment: You have a typo in your second line, it should be $-1(e_1-e_4)$

Comment: @VáclavMordvinov Ops yes, thanks I fix!

Comment: im not getting   if we  make  linear  combination ?  how can  i find the  eigenvalue

Comment: Simply $(e_1\pm e_4)$ are are 2 independent eigenvectors with eigenvalues $\pm 1$ and also $(e_2\pm e_5)$,$(e_3\pm e_6)$.

Comment: thanks@ gimusi  ..

Comment: @stupid You are welcome! Bye

Answer (score 3):

It's not too hard to find the determinant of $A-\lambda I$ by row operations.  In block form,
$$
    A - \lambda I = \begin{pmatrix} -\lambda I & I \\ I & - \lambda I \end{pmatrix}
$$
By swapping the first and third, second and fourth, and third and sixth rows of $A$, we see that its determinant is $-1$.  This tells us zero is not an eigenvalue.  Therefore, we may take the first, second, and third rows of $A-\lambda I$, multiply them by $\frac{1}{\lambda}$, and add them to the fourth, fifth, and sixth rows.  In block form, we have
$$
    \begin{vmatrix} -\lambda I & I \\ I & - \lambda I \end{vmatrix}
   =\begin{vmatrix} -\lambda I & I \\ 0 & (\lambda^{-1} - \lambda) I \end{vmatrix}
$$
The matrix on the right is upper-triangular, so the determinant is the product of the diagonal entries:
$$
    \begin{vmatrix} -\lambda I & I \\ 0 & (\lambda^{-1} - \lambda) I \end{vmatrix}
   =(-\lambda)^3(\lambda^{-1}-\lambda)^3 = (\lambda^2-1)^3
$$